# removing validators on an element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below html drill down control which is generated at run time..And i want to disable all the validations on it.

```
 <label class="mark" for="SupportTo_L1" id="SupportTo_L1_Label">select a value&nbsp;</label>

 <select aria-labelledby="SupportTo_L1_Label SupportTo_L1_Error" aria-required="true" 
         class="op-combobox" data-ishorizontal="true" data-drilldowntype="true"
         data-register-change-event="true" data-val="true"
         data-val-required="<img class='validateicon'              
         src='https://sxsvc.supp.maro.com/PAdvy0.0.0/Content/Images/16x16-red-alert.png'/><font color='Red'>*</font> Required"
         id="SupportTo_L1"
         name="SupportTo_L1" title="Technology group involved in the project:">

<button class="submitbutton" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" 
        value="submit">Submit</button>
```

But still it fires a validation on the this drill down when i clicked on the submit button.I tried the below code which didn't work.Anything else i need to disable.

```
$('#SupportTo_L1').attr(
     {'data-val':'false','aria-required':'false'}
    );
```

Comment: You have a typo. `$('#SSupportTo_L1')` should be `$('#SupportTo_L1')`.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly `SupportTo_L1` is a name not an Id

Comment: @iJay on the original question `SupportTo_L1` was an `id` on the `select` element.

Comment: I think the validator looks once at your form and caches the validators. Once the caching happens, modifying the attributes of the elements will have zero effect. You could disable the element itself, or to really remove validation (permanently), try `$('#SupportTo_L1').rules('remove');`

Comment: @Cory, your solution didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I have done it like that,

```
document.getElementById("elemenId").required = false;
```

Comment: What is `releasename`? Why would you use native JavaScript instead of jQuery?

Comment: It is just an example, there is no specific reason for using javascript. I feel i am in the drivers´ seat when i am using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
$('#SupportTo_L1').removeAttr('data-val');
$('#SupportTo_L1').removeAttr('aria-required');
```

Comment: @krrishna guess it depends on if you want remove the attribute, or modify its' value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#submit").click (function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$("select.op-combobox").attr("data-val","false");
$("select.op-combobox").attr("aria-required","false");
});
```

Comment: any reason we need to do it on the submit click explicitly ?

Comment: its just for example you can add .attr() fun anywhere in your submit section of jquery and e.preventDefault(); is for debug purpose here

Comment: if i do it on the click event by adding this exact code ,does it not overwrite the existing click event code ?